# How Sql Compare 2 different integer types

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

If i have a column_1 with column type as short (-32 768 and 32 767), If I write a sql query.

```
Select * 
from some_table 
where column_1 < 2147483647
```

Where 2147483647 is java INT_MAX. How does sql compare these types.

Comment: Likely by upcasting the short. But this may depend on the actual DBMS used. Please edit your question and include the DBMS you're using in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard appears to state only that the behaviour is implementation-defined.  (Meaning : RTFM of your particular DBMS.)  (And I'm open to standing corrected.)

However, for operations of *arithmetic* the standard seems to mandate quite some things that go in the direction of "avoid data truncation at all cost".  So it is not so unreasonable to assume that when it comes to numeric *comparisons*, the implementation will likewise do whatever it can to avoid any data truncation, i.e. in this particular case, "upcasting the SMALLINT to INTEGER".  But that's assumption not legislation.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the 2 datatypes is one of storage size and possible value range.

`SQL server` will handle implicit conversions (when necessary) for performing comparisons. In your case `short` will be converted to `int` as 'temp', then two values will be compared and 'temp' will be deleted.

So you don't have to be worry about it.